# How do I get the .apk url of an android app in the market?

Tags: android, download, apk

I have an HTC buzz, which has a smaller screen (QVGA) than most android phones. Now there is an application (hyves) which is in the market but when I scan their QR code or try it via appbrain it keeps saying Not Found. A frien of mine (who now is in belgium) has a G1 and I've copied the APK when he installed hyves. The app itself works fine just the icons are a little to large, but that is not annoying.

Now the problem, there is an update, and I cannot install it via the normal way. Is there a way to get the download URL of an APK in the market (via cyrket or so)? I can try to sniff my network when the phone trys to get an app but I'm not sure how to do that and if that would work...

Comment: http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me with Angry Birds.
You can try to:

- Install the android [simulator](http://lifehacker.com/5587260/how-to-test-drive-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone)
  with a modified ROM that has the
  market installed ([here it is how to
  do it](http://lifehacker.com/5588884/enable-the-android-market-when-trying-out-android-on-your-pc)).
- Install in the simulator the application you can't install in your phone
- Update it with market whenever there is an update
- Share the APK with [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTk0MDIxNDM5) or mail it, transfer to you PC or whatever is fine for you
- Download and install the new version in your physical phone

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that this application probably has some specific market filters enabled, so the market hides it from you. For example this app may decide (and report that to Android Market) that it shouldn't be run on QVGA screens, or that it shouldn't be run on your phone's Android version, etc etc. And for that reason Market won't show it to you.

But at the same time it finds itself suitable for your friend's phone, so it shows there.

So I guess whichever url you use - it won't help, market won't show it to you anyway.

The only option for you to install it is to find apk somewhere and install manually. Just as you did. And you'll have to repeat it for each and every update :)

So, find updated apk file ;)

Comment: And another way is write to author of application and ask him to enable QVGA-screens :)

Comment: Well, that is what I mean, how do I get the url of the APK file to download?